# GCP | How I can see all the working virtual machines on a project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wrote some code to automate the training procedure on our company vm instances.
you probably know that sometimes GCP can't provide you at the current moment with a machine - 'out of resource' exception.

so , I'd like to monitor which of my machines successfully turned on and which not.

if there is some way to show it on Bigquery it will be great.

thanks .

Comment: What do you want to do with the result? View it in a dashboard? Restart the VM automatically?

Comment: I have a batch of training commands. each one for each vm instance. I need to initialize number of vm's as my number of commands. the issue is how to handle cases which I'm failing to start a VM. 
@guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: You can use the Compute Engine API to get the VM status. If not RUNNING after a while (about 30s) try to restart it again. IMO, it's a perfect use case that you can scale with Cloud Workflow. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) functionality is good way for monitoring all you VMs.
Here is a detailed guide to implement [Monitoring on a Compute Engine Instance.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp)
Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google cloud's activity logs too:

> Activity logging is enabled by default for all Compute Engine
> projects.
>
> You can see your project's activity logs through the Logs Viewer in
> the Google Cloud Console:
>
> In the Cloud Console, go to the Logging page. Go to the Logging page
>
> When in the Logs Viewer, select and filter your resource type from the
> first drop-down list. From the All logs drop-down list, select
> compute.googleapis.com/activity_log to see Compute Engine activity
> logs.

Here is the [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/activity-logs).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).